# Python: Each element in different cell in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to write a program which paste each element of array into different row in excel. I have output like this (100 files looks like those below):

```
"name of file 1":
tab1=[2836, 13758, 14170, 16668]
"name of file 2":
tab2=[20703, 20918]
```

And I would like to get excel file looks like this:

```
name of file 1   name of file 2
    2836              20703
    13758             20918
    14170
    16668
```

But if I use the code below in loop, it only prints values from last tab (tab100)

```
for elem in files:
    for i in range(1, len(alert)):
         tab.append(object.index[i])
         df = pd.DataFrame({'name_of_file: ': tab })
         writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx')
         df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
         writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole code fragment with the loop please.

Answer (score 1):

I think the for loop is hard to read. I think you can do it if you follow these steps.

1) Use a for loop to create a dictionary that looks like this:

```
appended_data= {'Filename_one' : pd.Series([2836, 13758, 14170, 16668]), 'Filename_two': pd.Series([20703, 20918,45456, 35354])}
```

2) Create a DataFrame from the dictionary

```
df = pd.DataFrame(appended_data)
```

3) Tanspose your df

```
df = df.T
```

4) Write you df to Excel

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```